# Excel c# in computers Without visual basic

Tags: c#, excel, driver, basic

i made a project in c# that use excel, in my computer and other computers with visual basic the project works but in other computer when i Click the buttom Who start Work with excel i get exeption. 
Am i need to install some driver or something? Tnx

Comment: What interop libraries are you using?

Comment: Excel.workbook, excel.worksheet, i didnt install nothing.

Comment: If these are the Interop calls to MS.Office then you need MS-Office installed on the other computers. By the way saying _I get exception_ and not telling us  the exception message is, how to say without being rude ... useless?

Answer (score 0):

In Client system must have MS Office installed.